# PHP MESSAGE Issue

Tags: php, session

*SOLVED*

### The freaking error was having "inc" in the from address. CHANGED `$from = "messageform@courtesycareinc.com";` to `$from = "messageform@courtesycare.com";` and it worked.

I can't get this working. On another site I had, I used a similar method, but with a database and it works. When I use it this way without a database, for some reason it won't work. I can't get a message to send out.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
 $name = $_REQUEST['name']; 
 $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
 $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
 $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
 $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
 $semail = "yanikem@gmail.com";

 $name = htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES);
 $email = htmlspecialchars($email, ENT_QUOTES);
 $phone = htmlspecialchars($phone, ENT_QUOTES);
 $subject = htmlspecialchars($subject, ENT_QUOTES);
 $message = htmlspecialchars($message, ENT_QUOTES);

 $from = "messageform@courtesycareinc.com";
 $headers = "From: $from";
 $message .= "Courtesy Care, Inc. Contact\n\n"; 
 $message .= "The following information was collected from Courtesy Care, Inc.'s Contact Form.\n\n";
 $message .= "<table><tr><td>Name:&nbsp;</td><td>".$name."</td></tr><tr><td>Email:&nbsp;</td><td>".$email."</td></tr><tr><td>Phone:&nbsp;</td><td>".$phone."</td></tr><tr><td>Subject:&nbsp;</td><td>".$subject."</td></tr><tr><td>Message:&nbsp;</td><td>".$message."</td></tr></table>"; 

 mail($semail, "Courtesy Care, Inc.", $message, $headers); 

 header ('Location: contactusdone.php?say=msent');
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
 <table style="text-align:left; width: 500px; left:45px; position:relative; padding:2px; border:1px solid #1A1A1A">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align:top; text-align:center; border:1px solid #1A1A1A; background-color:#A52A2A; color:#FFFFFF;">MESSAGE FORM</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="2"><center>The form below can be used to send a detailed message to <strong>courtesycare@comcast.net</strong>.<br /><br /></center></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="80" align="right" valign="top">Name:&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="302" align="left" valign="top"><input name="name" type="text" style="width:98%" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top">Email:&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="email" type="text" style="width:98%" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top">Phone:&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="phone" type="text" style="width:98%" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top">Subject:&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="subject" type="text" style="width:98%" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top">Message:&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><textarea name="message" style="width:98%; height:150px;"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="reset" value="Clear Fields"> <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and then accept it, rather than editing it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the message is actually sending? Or, if it's sent, it's not getting dumped as spam?

PHP's `mail()` function essentially lies to you. If it returns `true`, that doesn't mean the mail got to the person it's addressed to, it just means that's it's been accepted into the mail system. Think of it as the difference between dropping a letter into a mailbox and the letter actually getting delivered - there's still plenty of ways for the postal system to shred the thing before it goes anywhere. All `mail()` will guarantee is that you dropped it into the mailbox.

Comment: I know when it's sent because I send it directly to me. This is the first time I'm having trouble with this.

Comment: I can't see what a database has to do with sending mail, other than producing data which goes into a mail message. Check the server's mail log to see what's happening to the message after PHP's handed it over to the local MTA (sendmail, postfix, exim, etc...). And check the return value from mail. If it's false, there was a problem sending it at the PHP level.

Comment: I think one of the problems was having "$message = $_REQUEST['message'];" which is the same variable and conflicts with "$message .=", I can't seem to see the other problem.

Comment: SOLVED The freaking error was having "inc" in the from address.$from = "messageform@courtesycareinc.com";